# Почему useEffect срабатывает дважды

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const[update,setUpdate]=useState(false)
const[data,setData]=useState([])
```

При отправке новых значений на сервер , useEffect срабатывает дважды и делает два get запроса

```
        useEffect(()=>{
                const AjaxData = async () =>{
                    const reasponse = await fetch(url,{
                        method:'GET',


                    });
                    const reasponseJson = await reasponse.json();
                    console.log(reasponseJson);
                    setData(reasponseJson);
                }


                AjaxData();
  },[update])
```

Вот функция добавления

```
function addUser (body){
        fetch(url,{
            method:'PUT',
            body:JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: headers,
        }).then(()=>setUpdate(!update));  


    }
```

Как избежать второй отправки get запроса

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` срабатывает дважды: при первом рендере компонента и при изменении зависимости `update`. Если ты хочешь чтобы он срабатывал единожды, оставь список зависимостей пустым

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, как у вас -

- повторный вызов срабатывает при изменении состояния update
- если нужно, чтобы useEffect срабатывал только при состоянии update=false, то в начале useEffect напишите проверку

```
useEffect(()=>{
     if(update)return 
    //... AjaxData() 
    },[update])
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
let fix = true
useEffect(() => {
  fix = !fix
  if (fix) return
  console.log(123)
   // ...
   // ...
}, [update])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]