# useEffect срабатывает каждый раз при изменении стейта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Изучаю React хуки, решила заменить метод жизненного цикла componentDidMount на useEffect, но он должен срабатывать один раз при первоначальном рендере, но срабатывает каждый раз при изменении стейта. В чем причина?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117262/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-useeffect-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторым аргументом можно передать стейт, по изменению которого будет происходить вызов `useEffect`. А если нужно, чтобы `useEffect` отработал единожды, можно указать пустой массив или `[null]`. Вот [документация](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html))

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your code
}, [null]);
```